# Since when does Valhalla exist in Norse mythology?

Tags: norse, european-folklore, valhalla

Since when does Valhalla exist in Norse mythology ? Like (almost) all **Indo-Europeans** the Vikings believed in a cycle of *life*, *death* and *rebirth*. Valhalla contradicts this fundamental content of Norse mythology a bit. So was Valhalla introduced in a late 'stratum' of mythology or how did the concept of Valhalla develop ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No one knows specifically when Valhalla became a part of Norse mythology, but it was -as far as we know- first recorded in the stanzas of a 10th century poem commemorating the  Eric Bloodaxe known as [Eiríksmál](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eir%C3%ADksm%C3%A1l). This skaldic poem as compiled in [Fagrskinna](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kings%27_sagas), a latter work written in 1220 that is know as one of the kings' sagas, a series of old Norse tales and the story that [codified Valhalla for many Norse and non-Norse peoples](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Valhalla#Attestations).